# How to remove "Translate to" for content / pages in TYPO3 8 LTS?

Tags: php, typo3, translation, typo3-8.7.x, lts

I'm using TYPO3 8 LTS and trying to remove the String "[Translate to XY]", when create translated content and pages.

In earlier TYPO3 versions it was possible to solve this with the following code in extTables.php:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['bodytext']['l10n_mode'] = '';
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['header']['l10n_mode'] = '';
```

(Link: https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/how-to-remove-translate-to-and-copy-tags-in-typo3/)

I've tried it with same code in ext_tables.php and TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php. => That didn't work for me.

Have anyone an idea how to solve this or the new way to do it?

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$TCA` with `$GLOBALS['TCA']` inside *Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php*:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['bodytext']['l10n_mode'] = '';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['header']['l10n_mode'] = '';
```

Alternatively you could set an empty string with Page TSconfig:

```
TCEMAIN.translateToMessage =
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. :) I tried first to set translateToMessage to empty string. The "Translate to:" still appears. To set l10n_mode via $GLOBALS[...] is working. It set l10n_mode to empty string, but "Translate to:" also appears in the pagetitle of translated pages (Seems to be the standard typo3 behavior). Is there something special for pagetitles?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @[sebkIn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157290/sebkln)

**Remove "[Translate to XY:]" from translated content**

> Replace $TCA with $GLOBALS['TCA'] inside Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:
>
> $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['bodytext']['l10n_mode'] = '';
>
> $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['header']['l10n_mode'] = '';

**Remove "[Translate to XY:]" from translated pagetitle**

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['title']['l10n_mode'] = 'exclude';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TCEMAIN.table.pages.disablePrependAtCopy = 1
TCEMAIN.table.tt_content.disablePrependAtCopy = 1
```

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceMain.html#translatetomessage

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most relevant and important parts of the link you provided in the answer itself. This helps prevent that part of your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working for whatever reason.

Comment: Of course you're right. But the answer is in the two lines above the link. It's an answer, not a tutorial. Anyone working with TYPO3 will know it from there. But perhaps I overlook something, so, what do you miss?